# Cannot resolve method 'newBuilder' in 'StorageOptions'

Tags: java, windows, google-cloud-storage

This line of code

```java
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

gives me this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'newBuilder' in 'StorageOptions'
```

I have imported both `com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;` and `com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;`

The line comes from the official doc here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-java

I don't understand why because the rest works fine.

Comment: Hey there! Could you please share with us the complete error message you are getting? and also, from where you are executing this code? (From local, from App Engine, Cloud Functions etc).

Comment: Receiving same error.  Error stack - `Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
XXXX.java:[22,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method newBuilder()
  location: class com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions`
 Same code as mentioned in query, and all dependencies updated.

Comment: After checking the code, I found pom had gcloud-java-storage imported instead of google-cloud-storage
Updating the pom fixed the issue.